# Recording Script in Jmeter that does not require Correlation. Just like TruClient in LoadRunner

Tags: jmeter, correlation, recording

Is there anyway to record script for JMeter (.JMX) that does not require Correlation. As in LoadRunner if you record script in TruClient Protocol that script does not require correlation. It runs on Chromium?

I will appreciate response.

Thanks

Saleem Soomro

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. If you want to use real browser for replaying recorded actions you can check out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en), it can record "browser only" actions which can later be replayed using [Selenium](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium.md) executor of [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) framework
2. If you want to use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters check out [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) which is capable of exporting recorded scripts in SmartJMX mode. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Comment: I don't want to replay in browser. I like to create script .jmx file the application has login as well. The server sends JSession IDs etc, lots of Dynamic data. I like to find a way so that don't have to deal with Correlation. Just like creating script in TruClient for LoadRunner does not require Correlation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  [Web Driver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin.
It runs a real browser and does not require correlation (in LR's terms).

Recording is not supported out of the box so you'd have to make use of the 'Script' field.

You could also try to employ [BlazeMeter's Chrome extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) to record the selenium script which could be used as the base for your Web Driver Sampler script.